# What is Olympic dumbbell?

Tags: dumbbells

What is olympic dumbbell?

Is it a kind of dumbbell or just a dumbbell brand name?

Is it something different from ordinary dumbbell?

Comment: Did you Google it? If not then you should.

Comment: @HelpingHands Of course I did. I couldn't find an answer

Comment: @HelpingHands If you can google and find an answer, please provide me the link

Comment: It's probably a dumbbell handle that's compatible with olympic plates.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is easy to google

Comment: I'm voting to keep it open. I've never heard of an olympic dumbbell, and Google only yields results for shopping and reviews. It isn't immediately clear if it's a brand or a class of equipment.

Comment: @FredrikD lots of things are easy to google, but we're (or at least I am) here to provide high quality source based answers, and that can be difficult to find via a google search.

Answer (score 3):

As I heard of it the first time, I thought that would be a joke as I just knew about olympic barbells aka Bars with a specific diameter for holding olympic plates ex. Eleiko etc. on them.

After looking around I noticed those dumbbells where you can do the same: 
Dumbell bars for Olympic plates, holes no less than 2" (50.8mm).
On Amazon you can buy some of these.
[http://www.amazon.com/Olympic-Dumbbell-Handles-sold-Pair/dp/B002OB2BT6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002OB2BT6)

Comment: Let me just slap some 20kg Eleiko plates on those dumbbells, and I'm ready to curl!

Comment: Why not... you can do some one arm snatches too ... try those ... are awesome :-).

Comment: I do them with a regular barbell for whole body strengthening, never considered dumbbells though... would be fun. One arm benching would be challenging too ..